# CSS Clone everything except a div

Tags: jquery, clone

I want to clone a div, without a specific children.

```
var clone = $(this).parent().parent().clone(true);
```

But I want to delete a div inside the clone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your div has a unique ID you could just tack on some more methods at the end.

```
var clone = $(this).parent().parent().clone(true).find('div#id_name').remove();
```

Comment: Can't you just do `.remove('div#id_name')` instead of `.find()`?

Comment: I'm not certain that simply .remove() would take its pick from just the descendant nodes of the cloned node whereas .find() only selects from descendants.

Comment: OP should test it :) Anyway, it doesnt change anything, just shorter (if it work)

Comment: Agreed.  And report back.  Granted, it wouldn't be difficult to set up a fiddle ourselves and see.

Comment: You should first find it, and than remove it. Remove function doesn't remove a specific div, it just deletes a div that is found.